# Empty Get when rewrite with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a booking software and i'm trying to get the booking hash from $_GET but the PHP file is getting the var empty when i use var_dump to test.

Here is what PHP shows:

```
array(1) { ["hash"]=> string(1) ""}
```

Here is the HTACCESS code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^booking/[a-fA-F0-9]{32}/?$ booking.php?hash=$1
```

I guess the regular expression is fine, honestly i been coding two days long without sleep in php and i'm not apache expert, i need a couple of eyes more to see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^booking/([a-fA-F0-9]{32})/?$ booking.php?hash=$1`

Comment: PD of [what does $1 in .htaccess file mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24922079)

Comment: @arkascha, yo thanks dude, i seriously need to learn regular expressions deeper.

Comment: A look into the documentation of the tool you use would have helped better: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html